# On the boundary conditions of $u''+\frac{1}{t} u'=f(t) $ so that $v(x, y)=u(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and $g(x, y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ solves $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=g$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Have a look at this multiple select question:

Q. Let $u$ be a solution of the boundary value problem  $$\begin{array}{c}u^{\prime \prime}+\frac{1}{t} u^{\prime}=f(t), t \in(0,1), \\ u^{\prime}(0)=a, u(1)=b,\end{array}~~~~~~~~~~~(*) $$ Define for $x^2+y^2 \leq 1, v(x, y)=u\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ and $g(x, y)=f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$, then $v$ is the solution of the PDE $$v_{x x}+v_{y y}=g,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(**)$$ in $\left\{(x, y): x^2+y^2<1\right\}, v(x, y)=0$ on $\left\{(x, y): x^2+y^2=1\right\}$ if

(1) $a>0$ and $b>0$

(2) $a>0$ and $b=0$

(3) $a=0$ and $b=0$

(4) $a<0$ and $b=0$

Observe that $(*)$ is equivalent to $(**)$ for $t=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in (0,1)$, and for instance,
I got that $a=0$ is necessary for the trivial choice $f=0$ as the general solution $$u(t)=c_1+c_2 \ln t,$$ for $(*)$ must be realistic towards $u'(0)$. That is, option (3) seems true as long as $f(t)=0$ however I couldn't verify for arbitrary $f$.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ya...correct, I made a mistake, and what is the intuition to choose such a particular solution?